# How to duplicate polygons in QGIS 3.0 with python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, polygon

My background is in arcpy and Esri so all of the Qgis is new to me.

So I cannot figure out how to duplicate polygon with python. I want to draw one polygon and then be able to use it to make more and make a grid of them like I am showing below in the picture.

What should I do?
What resources should I look at? (I have looked at the documentation but doesn't make sense to me)

```
from qgis.core import *

layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"path/Test_file.shp", "Test_file", "ogr")

feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]

The_Features = layer.getFeatures()
num=0
for i in The_Features:
    geom = i.geometry()


    Point_1 = geom.vertexAt(0)
    raw1 = Point_1.asWkt()
    Point_1_x = float(raw1[7:29])
    Point_1_y = float(raw1[31:51])
    print(raw1)

    Point_2 = geom.vertexAt(1)
    raw2 = Point_2.asWkt()
    Point_2_x = float(raw2[7:29])
    Point_2_y = float(raw2[31:51])
    print(raw2)

    Point_3 = geom.vertexAt(2)
    raw3 = Point_3.asWkt()
    Point_3_x = float(raw3[7:29])
    Point_3_y = float(raw3[31:51])
    print(raw3)

    Point_4 = geom.vertexAt(3)
    raw4 = Point_4.asWkt()
    Point_4_x = float(raw4[7:29])
    Point_4_y = float(raw4[31:51])
    print(raw4)
    print(Point_4_x)
    print(Point_4_y)
    num+=1
    break

 print(num)
 # Set the provider to accept the data source
 prov = layer.dataProvider()
 points = [QgsPointXY(Point_1_x,Point_1_y), QgsPointXY(Point_2_x,Point_2_y), 
 QgsPointXY(Point_3_x,Point_3_y), QgsPointXY(Point_4_x,Point_4_y)]

 # Add a new feature and assign the geometry
 feat = QgsFeature()
 feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY( [points]))
 prov.addFeatures([feat])

 # Update extent of the layer
 layer.updateExtents()
```

[image]

Comment: please edit your question to correct the code formatting.

Comment: Is it right now?

Comment: yep, looks good. you should see your posts preview live at the bottom of the question interface or via the *Preview* button in the app!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to create a grid from a single polygon (the left-bottom; the polygons will be created to the right and above it). Make sure your initial layer has only one polygon in the desired 'starting point' and run this code:

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"path/Test_file.shp", "Test_file", "ogr")

rows=4
columns=4

xfactor=500 #space interval x in meters (assuming projected CRS)
yfactor=200 #space interval y in meters (assuming projected CRS)

feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]
geom = feats[-1].geometry() 


for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        Point_1 = geom.vertexAt(0)
        raw1 = Point_1.asWkt()
        Point_1_x = float(raw1[7:29])+(xfactor*j)
        Point_1_y = float(raw1[31:51])+(yfactor*i)
        print(raw1)

        Point_2 = geom.vertexAt(1)
        raw2 = Point_2.asWkt()
        Point_2_x = float(raw2[7:29])+(xfactor*j)
        Point_2_y = float(raw2[31:51])+(yfactor*i)
        print(raw2)

        Point_3 = geom.vertexAt(2)
        raw3 = Point_3.asWkt()
        Point_3_x = float(raw3[7:29])+(xfactor*j)
        Point_3_y = float(raw3[31:51])+(yfactor*i)
        print(raw3)

        Point_4 = geom.vertexAt(3)
        raw4 = Point_4.asWkt()
        Point_4_x = float(raw4[7:29])+(xfactor*j)
        Point_4_y = float(raw4[31:51])+(yfactor*i)
        print(raw4)

        prov = layer.dataProvider() 
        points = [QgsPointXY(Point_1_x,Point_1_y), QgsPointXY(Point_2_x,Point_2_y), QgsPointXY(Point_3_x,Point_3_y), QgsPointXY(Point_4_x,Point_4_y)]

        feat = QgsFeature() 
        feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY( [points])) 
        prov.addFeatures([feat])

layer.updateExtents()
```

**Example Input:**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

A side note, that if you are to repeat this process on existing layers, consider using a [GeoPackage](https://www.geopackage.org/), as overwriting and deleting features from a single shapefile has proved to be erroneous when I tested.